# Best way to rotate (and translate) a set of points in python

Tags: python, math, graph, rotation

I have two sets of points `(x,y)` that I have plotted with matplotlib

Just visually I can see that it seems there is some kind of rotation between those.

I would like to rotate one set of points around a certain point (would like to try several points of rotation) and plot them again.

What would be the best way to rotate said set of points with python?

I have read that perhaps shapely could be used but a simple example would help me understand how.

Comment: Note that "apply a given rotation to a given cloud of points" and "find the rotation that best maps a given cloud of points to another given cloud of points" are two different problems.

Comment: To find the best transformation between two clouds of points, one way is to use [the Iterative Closest Point algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point). For instance using [open3d.registration.registration_icp](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.8.0/python_api/open3d.registration.registration_icp.html)

Comment: One important question: do you already know which point from the first set should be mapped to which point to the second set? I.e., do you have points A, B, C, D in the first set and A', B', C', D' in the second set, and you want to find the rotation that maps A to A', B to B', C to C', D to D', etc? Or do you have points A,B,C,D in the first set and points E,F,G,H in the second set and you don't know whether A maps to E,F,G or H?

Comment: @Stef Unfortunately the two lines don't have a 1-1 correspondence. In fact after rotating them I would like to see how different they are.

Comment: In general if you don't know the correspondence or there is no exact correspondence, ICP (Iterative Closest Point) might be a simple algorithm that can work. But If you already know that your point clouds represent a particular shape, such as a line, then perhaps it might be better to find the transformation by working on a representation of the shape rather than on the point clouds. Maybe [RanSaC (random sample consensus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) can be helpful.

Comment: @Stef ICP seems really interesting. Tomorrow I am going to try and find a simple example of this to try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy to store your points

For example, if you have a nx2 array, each line being a point, like this

```py
xy=np.array([[50, 60],
             [10, 30],
             [30, 10]])
```

You can plot them like this

```py
plt.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1])
```

And to rotate them, you need a rotation matrix

```py
def rotateMatrix(a):
    return np.array([[np.cos(a), -np.sin(a)], [np.sin(a), np.cos(a)]])
```

You can apply this matrix to your `xy` set of points like this

```py
newxy = xy @ rotateMatrix(a).T
```

Note that I transpose the rotation matrix, to keep acuracy. But, in this case, because of the specific form of rotation matrix, you could generate directly the transposed one by just passing -a

```py
newxy = xy @ rotateMatrix(-a)
```

If you need no rotate around a center (x0,y0) other than (0,0), just rotate not xy but xy-(x0,y0) (that is the displacement vector from center to points), and then add that rotated vector to the center.

```py
newxy = (xy-[x0,y0]) @ rotateMatrix(-a) + [x0,y0]
```

Application

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib
import time

def rotateMatrix(a):
    return np.array([[np.cos(a), -np.sin(a)], [np.sin(a), np.cos(a)]])

xy=np.random.randint(0,100, (200,2))

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], 'o')
plt.xlim(-30,130)
plt.ylim(-50,110)

plotdata,=plt.plot(xy[:,0], xy[:,1],'o')

x0=20
y0=50

def anim(i):
   newxy=(xy-[x0,y0]) @ rotateMatrix(-2*i*np.pi/180) + [x0,y0]
   plotdata.set_data(newxy[:,0], newxy[:,1])
   return [plotdata]

theAnim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim, interval=40, blit=False, frames=360, repeat=False)
#theAnim.save('rotate.nosync.gif')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. Quick question. This is rotating the points around (0,0) right? Is there a way to include rotation around other point? I suppose the rotation matrix needs to include that info too...

Comment: @KansaiRobot Either in the rotation matrix. But that means having a 3x3 rotation matrix in homogeneous coordinates, and then also having a n×3 xy1 list of points. In your case, easiest way is probably to just remove the center from xy before rotation, and add it back after rotation. I edit my answer accordingly